# How to change state of component based on actions of parallel component in React (using React Router)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, router, react-router-dom

I have my App.js file structured in a way where the header and footer are always present, regardless of the page the user is in. The issue is that when a user modifies some data in a parallel component, the link transfers the user to the default page but the data in the header does not get modified. The header only gets updated once i refresh the page after the actions in the other component have been set by the user. If it helps, the data is coming from localStorage. I've tried prop drilling and messing around with state but no luck. Refreshing the pages programmatically also gives me unwanted behavior.
The route where the data is being modified is 
`<Route path="/item/:id" render={(props) => <Item {...props} />}/>` 
And here is the app.js file:

#### App.js File

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

function App(){
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    return (
        <Router>
            <Header/> {/* <-- ALWAYS PRESENT */}
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/' exact component={Products} />
                <Route path='/contact' component={Contact}/>
                <Route path='/cart' component={Cart}/>
                <Route path="/item/:id" render={(props) => <Item {...props} />}/> 
            </Switch>
            <Footer date={currentYear} /> {/* <-- THIS AS WELL */}
        </Router>
    )
}
```

If anyone wants to see the structure of the code in the Header or Item components let me know,  but I'm wondering if there is a way React Router can handle these types of actions.

Comment: Could you do something like extract a common layout component that you render that wraps the inner component? That way the header and footer will be re-rendered on path changes? Another option could be to have a component inside the the router and wrapping the heade, switch and footer that's getting the stuff you need from local storage on path change and passing it down via context - then your head and footer could hook into that context?

Answer (score 0):

React components only can render data they know about. This data consists of their props and their state. When some side effect occurs, you update data and react rerenders your components. If you want to share data between components, you can do it in three ways - store it higher in tree, use dedicated data management solution or duplicate it in some way.

Considering your situation, you have three options. First is to keep data your components interested in App. Second would be to use some external state management solution and do it in a way said solution works.

Since you keep this data in localStorage, you have third option. In your header you can subscribe to [localStorage changes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) and update state of your header. Beware, that simply putting everything from localStorage into state on every render can be costly, so try do do it only when data *definitely* changed.